# Is there a proper way to colorize image generated with CITextImageGenerator?

Tags: ios, swift, core-image, cifilter

I found several solutions including blending and changing hue, but they all look rather hacky to me.

I wonder whether there is any 'proper' way of colorising B&W images - preferably using exclusively CoreImage but without writing a custom CIFilter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it seems that custom metal CIFilter is the easiest way after all -

```html
    float4 colorize(sample_t s, float4 rgba) {
        if (s.a == 0.0) {
            return s.rgba;
        } else {
            rgba[3] = s.a;
            return rgba;
        }
    }
```

Comment: *"...but without writing a custom CIFilter"*. This doesn't really answer the actual question. (But yes, I agree that writing an actual CIKernel is the best route to go.)

Comment: I know, I basically gave up searching for a simpler solution :)